# Problem installing conky package - ./configure not found

Tags: software-installation, compiling, conky

I am trying to install [this package](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) but when I go to the source folder and type `./configure` I get

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

If I try `sh ./configure` I get

```
sh: 0: Can't open ./configure
```

So the makefile cannot be created and I can't install the package. I have successfully compiled & installed packages in the past so I do not understand why is this happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you first run `./autogen.sh` before `./configure`

Comment: Nope, but I have just tried and I get the same result for `./autogen.sh`

Comment: Are you in the right directory? You must be able to see the `autogen.sh` file with `ls`. You need to `cd` into the directory after cloning or extracting

Comment: I am in the `/src` and there is not the `autogen.sh` file. Neither in any other directory.

Comment: You can install it using `sudo apt-get install conky` if you don't need it compiled from source

Comment: This is what I have done for the moment, but still I would like to know the solution to this question.

Comment: Ok got it to install see steps below

Comment: A cursory glance seems to indicate that conky abandoned automake and autoconf for cmake in 2009, i.e. 8 years ago. How old is the documentation you are reading?

Comment: I was reading the documentation included in the package. Apparently that is old and the updated documentation is only shown in the wiki page of their github repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to install it like this:

1. First download latest release from `https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/releases/tag/v1.10.6`
2. extract it with `tar` and move to `home`:

   ```
   tar -xvf conky-1.10.6.tar.gz
   mv conky-1.10.6 ~/
   ```
3. Using the `ccmake` method as stated for versions `1.10` and later:

   1. Install these packages:

      ```
      sudo apt install libtolua-dev libtolua++5.1-dev
      sudo apt install libx11-dev libxft-dev libxdamage-dev libncurses5-dev  libxinerama-dev
      sudo apt install cmake-curses-gui
      ```
   2. Run these in `/home/$USER`:

      ```
      mkdir build
      cd build 
      ccmake $HOME/conky-1.10.6
      ```
   3. Press <kbd>c</kbd> on the keyboard when the `cmake GUI` appears. This will build the files in the `build` directory
   4. Then run make and install:

      ```
      make
      sudo make install
      ```
4. Re-run `ccmake .` in the build directory if the files don't generate.

Source:

https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Installation